# How to connect the plotted points by a line in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have my model's mesh cells corner coordinates and I want to visualise my model mesh now, by connecting the corners to get a rectangular mesh.

In my script I have defined the following commands to draw a line between the given points (the data are from a netcdf file). I can connect the cross points vertically. But I would like to draw the dashed lines horizontally (say connect the red points horizontally).  My script so far is like the following:

```
xqu,yqu = map(qulon,qulat)  #-- u vectors lat/lon
xqv,yqv = map(qvlon,qvlat)  #-- v vectors lat/lon

#--plot zonal vector point (u) and connect to eachother (vertical cell walls)
vectsu= map.plot(xqu,yqu, '-', color='Indigo',linewidth=1,markerfacecolor='b', markersize=10)

#--plot meridional vector point (vsi) and connect to eachother (horizontal cell walls)
vectsv= map.plot(xqv,yqv, '-',  color='g',linewidth=1,markerfacecolor='b', markersize=10)
```

[image: see the resulted image here]

How can I connect these points horizontally?

Comment: Does `map.plot(xqu.transpose(), yqu.transpose())` (or `xqv.transpose(), yqv.transpose()`) get you close?

Comment: Yes it did work! Thanks for the hint :)